# osx mono winforms undesirably stays always on top

Tags: c#, winforms, macos, mono

I made an app in c# using VS 2013 Windows Forms(.NET3.5), tested it positively on Ubuntu - no problems (using mono).

Now it comes to test in on MacOS Maverick 10.9 with mono installed.

No matter what, my form stays on top, even `MessageBox.Show(this,"blah");` is covered by form.

What i tried so far:
Set TopMost to in designer view.
Added `this.TopMost = false;` to public `Form1(){}`.

Any ideas how could i solve this issue?

My form is without borders, controlboxes. Instead of this i use Image as background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i got small function which will detect if it's Mac and then change `FormBorderStyle`

```
 if (OSDetection.os == "MAC")  // Mac fix for always on top
            {
                this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            }
```

It seems i cannot set border to none, since my form will be displayed always on top of other windows.